# Problema com alinhamento de campo bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, css

Estou enfrentando um problema, qual não consigo solucionar. 
 
O que desejo parece ser simples, alinhar o pequeno campo bem abaixo da escrita quantidade, fiz alguns testes com métodos que vi pelo mestre `google`, mas o campo insiste em ficar travado pelo meio.

```
<!-- Caixa Quantidade -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <form id="formExemplo" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="textNome" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input id="textNome" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="" type="text">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Fim caixa Quantidade -->
```

Comment: Tá faltando uma coluna na tr do while, nao? Cabeçalho tem 4, corpo tem 3.

Comment: Bem verifiquei parece que não, o problema maior é como alinhar, a caixa de quantidade não se move para nenhum lado.